# Unable to translate SVG clip-path

Tags: html, css, svg

I have an image clipped with SVG `clip-path`. And I'm trying to move this `clip-path`, but with `translateX` the image dissapears. Looks like the problem is in `clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox"`. How can I move the path?

```css
svg {
  position: absolute;
}

picture {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

/* #shape {
  transform: translateX(1px);
} */
```

```html
<svg class="hero-svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="2560px" height="1164px" viewBox="0 0 1280 582" version="1.1">
        <clipPath id="mask-path" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
            <path 
                id="shape" 
                fill="#E5EFF7"
                d='M0, 0 L1, 0 L1, 0.4996753848797251 C0.909334453125, 0.6 0.7926289296875, 0.75 0.6498834375, 0.6158118900343643 C0.4357651953125, 0.401758644329897 0.366062217578125, 0.5330226374570446 0.20884810625, 0.5184233780068728 C0.104038698828125, 0.5086905378006873 0.034422663203124995, 0.4739563067010309 0, 0.4142206847079038 Z'
            />  
        </clipPath>
    </svg>
<picture id="hero-bg" style="clip-path: url(#mask-path); -webkit-clip-path: url(#mask-path);">
  <img src="https://www.google.es/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" alt="Doctors" style="width:100%;">
</picture>
```

I use Google Chrome Version 66.0.3359.181. In Safari `translateX` do nothing.

There is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yhw8soq0/

Thanks.

Comment: `clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox"` means your clip path sits in a 1px*1px square that is mapped to the bounding box of the clipped object. You can move it, but anything above 1px will move it completely out of the area of the clipped image. Using percentage units for the transform should get you better control.

Comment: @ccprog, thanks, the 1x1 box helped me, it works in the Chrome, but in Safari and FF the box looks like 0x0.